# how can i check a date with current date

Tags: php, html, sql, time, strtotime

```
if ((strtotime("1 June") == time()))
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection

    mysql_select_db("student");

    $order = "UPDATE stud SET class='9' WHERE class='8'";

    $result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
}
```

the above code does not work..i changed my date to 1 june..but strtotime() and time() returns different values..

Comment: time give you the value by counting current date and that's why its not giving you same value as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cmp = strtotime("19 April");

// convert specified date to int
$current_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));


if ($cmp == $current_date) {
    // process
}
```

the time() function will give you and equivalent of

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

if want to compare the current date and the date given use only

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
```

that will give result to the format of

```
strtotime("19 April");
```

check documentation of strtotime and date
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Why would you use `date()` function to get today date? Why not just use `today` keyword in `strtotime()`??? Like this [example](https://eval.in/315515).

Comment: yeah it can.. and all people has different ways to solve problems. thanks for that.. link

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to check the time against a date see [php time function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

try using the date function instead `date('jS F');`

again see [php date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)